# Using the SCS conference template with multiple authors separated with \and

Tags: titles

Using the style provided by the conference at http://www.scs.org/ (http://www.scs.org/upload/documents/templates/ConferenceSubmissionLaTeXTemplate.tar.gz), multiple authors with multiple affiliations are recommended to use two columns to display the authors; however, the overwritten `\maketitle` command does not allow use of the `\and` separator in the `\author` definition.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{scs}

\begin{document}
\title{Something}
\author{Author1\\
Affiliation1
\and
Author2\\
Affiliation2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

results in:

```
! Misplaced \crcr.
\endtabular ->\crcr
\egroup \egroup $\egroup
l.48 \maketitle
```

What is the best way to either redefine the `\and` correctly, or override the author portion of the template's `\maketitle` command to allow multicolumn display of authors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style simply typesets what you input inside a `center` environment. It's not really clear what they mean by “you can use multiple columns”. One way would be to use a `tabular` environment:

```
\author{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  A. Uthor                & W. Riter \\
  University of Somewhere & University of Anytown \\
\end{tabular}
}
```

that gives

[image]

Or possibly they want them listed like

```
\author{
  A. Uthor\\ University of Somewhere \\[2ex]
  W. Riter\\ University of Anytown
}
```

I added some vertical separation. Surely `\and` means nothing in this context.

Comment: I was debating doing exactly this or modifying the template - thanks for confirming my suspicions and for the very helpful example!

On a side note, if someone encountering the same problem is playing around and includes \usepackage{authblk}, you'll get this error with egreg's recommended solution (simply remove the extraneous \usepackage{authblk} to resolve):

    ! Use of \\author doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a {
                             \def \@currenvir {tabular}\edef \@currenvline {

Comment: @Jon I wouldn't modify the template, particularly if they ask for the TeX file. If they ask only for the PDF it might be; but still I wouldn't do it.